# Error al crear archivo mediante touch en Powershell

Tags: powershell

Acostumbrado a utilizar terminal de Linux, al comenzar a trabajar con Powershell que contiene comandos linux, no me crea archivo .bat mediante comando "touch" como en linux. ¿Qué sucede?

```
touch ejemplo.bat
```

**el término touch no se reconoce como cmdlet...**

Answer (score 2):

**Powershell** tienen sus propios comandos, no son los de Linux.

Si quieres crear un archivo, necesitas el comando **New-Item** o su alias **ni**.

Ejemplo: Crear un nuevo archivo llamado hola.txt

```
> ni hola.txt
```

Esto te creará un archivo llamado hola.txt, de manera similar al comando **touch** de Linux. Consulta la ayuda con **Get-Help** **New-Item** para más ejemplos.